# enableBatch property in Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm very new to Apache ActiveMQ and still in learning phase so please bear with my silly or with not very precise questions. I would like to know is there is any possibility of message lost if we keep enablebatch property to true?

As per my knowledge enabling batch processing is always helpful and enhance your performance too in terms of processing transaction but I would like to know negative side of this property which may lead to message lost issue. Also if you can let me know whether there are some additional properties too which may need to set if we enable batch as true ?

Will appreciate your response

Regards,
Deepak Hardasani

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, please elaborate on the configuration you are trying to enable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pre-tune! It only leads to de-tuning. Most Enterprise message flows are sufficiently handled with defaults on modern server systems without jumping through a lot of hoops and adding complexity.

Build up a representative test case.. run it. If the numbers meet your requirements, move on to more useful tasks. If not, then worry about tuning.